# Including files in namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, include

I have small problem with name spaces in php 5.3.
I've made declaration for namespace:

```
use \com\me\libs as Libs;
```

And I can't find answer how to include file in that namespace using "Libs"...
I can do

```
include('com/me/libs/functions.php');
```

but I'm trying to find more "clear" way to do this... Like declaring object:

```
$foo = new Libs\Foo.php
```

And second question.
I'm trying to make php file returning JSON array. To do this I have to include "Connection.php" class. But when I include this file (same folder) I got error with implementation file not found (same folder, same namespace)...

Comment: Second question: Whats the error message?

Comment: `Fatal error: Class 'com\me\libs\ConnAbstract' not found in C:\wamp\www\mysite\1\com\me\libs\Connection.php on line 5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question: You can use an autoloader. See [spl_autoload_register()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.spl-autoload-register.php) for further information.

Comment: Thank You. That helped. But is there a method to include for example header file with pure html?